# Zabbix: Trying to create email alert from trigger if url is unreachable/down

Tags: regex, triggers, zabbix

I'm using Zabbix and trying to setup an a trigger to email me if a url is down.
I'm under configuration > Templates > My Web Template.
Under items I have:
web.page.regexp[mysite,url/to/test/,PORT,OK,2].
The trigger is:
(({Template My Web Template to URL Check:web.page.regexp[mysite,url/to/test/,PORT,OK,2].regexp(OK)})#1)

Now if remove the last / just to test Zabbix will create an alert but will not send an email trigger.
From the zabbix server if I use a Zabbix_get with the removed / it returns an "EOF" (which is fine as I want to see what a failure looks like). With the correct URL it returns "OK".

Am I using the wrong expression for emails?

Comment: Did you define an [action](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/notifications/action)?

Comment: yes, shouldn't the trigger work though?

Comment: Is the trigger shown with the *PROBLEM* state under _Monitoring_ > _Triggers_ respectively _Events_? Further, are there actions listed in the very right column? Maybe the email is sent but can't leave the host?

Comment: If I "break" the url then I see the trigger as a warning/high/etc. I just don't receive an email alert.

Comment: I think I fixed it. I didn't set the alert level high enough.